# Webex API Usage without using Personal Domain

Tags: webex, web-extensibility

I want to use Webex API [www.webex.com] to create meeting from my site.

For that I need my own domain in the case of **URL API** in this way:

"https://yourWebExHostedName.webex.com/yourWebExHostedName/".

And in the case **XML API**, I need **WebexID**, **SiteID**, **ParternerID**.

Those are mentioned in this Webex official document.

https://developer.cisco.com/documents/4733862/4736679/URL+API+WBS+27+Ref+Guide.pdf

I want to say that these parameters are available in testing environment.

But I don't have my own domain to use this API in production environment.

So I want to know that it is possible to use this API in production environment without owning a domain.

Do you have any Idea? Have you faced such problem? I need urgent solution regarding that.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I need this as well.

Comment: @MarkHughes: Still I did not find any solution.

Comment: Their email support is terrible, passed about 3 emails back and forth, and they haven't replied to two emails.

Had to get client to contact their support, after being sent around and circles for a while they were told it can't happen unless they're paying for the whole deal - very unfortunate.

Due to their terrible support, I'm not going to add support for their product

Answer (score 0):

For the XML API, you can obtain those parameters from this page (you need to login or register first to be able to see the form):

https://developer.cisco.com/site/webex-developer/develop-test/try-webex-apis/

To test the API, all the requests would be made to the sandbox site https://apidemoeu.webex.com

Answer (score 0):

No

You cam't go for production without Webexdomain. Because For recording of video,Host users's and Attendee user's it take space on server to stored all this data you need your web-ex hosting site.